# Using GetEnumerator for Dictionary initialization C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, static, initialization, enumeration

I have a class `Cluster.cs` defined as:

```
public class Cluster
{
        protected int _clusterID = -1;
        private static int _clusterCount = 0;

        protected int _attributeCount;
        // _clusterObjects contains EvoObjects in this cluster. 
        protected List<EvoObject> _clusterObjects = new List<EvoObject>();

        /** _nkA[_i] is the total occurrences of the attribute _i in this cluster*/
        protected Int32[] _nkA;

        // For each attribute, record their values as KeyValuePair.

        protected Dictionary<Int32, UtilCS.KeyCountMap<Int32>> _attributeValues = new Dictionary<Int32, UtilCS.KeyCountMap<Int32>>();

        public Cluster(int _clusterID, int _attributeCount)
        {
            this._clusterID = _clusterID;
            this._attributeCount = _attributeCount;
            _nkA = new Int32[_attributeCount];
        }

        // Initialize _attributeValues
        IEnumerable<Int32>  _range = Enumerable.Range(0, _attributeCount).GetEnumerator(_i => {_attributeValues[_i] = new UtilCS.KeyCountMap<Int32>()});
}
```

while initializing `_attributeValues`, I got error as:

> "No overloaded method for GetEnumerator takes 1 argument"

whereas I've only 1 argument to initialize i.e. `_attributeValues` which is actually a dictionary that's why have to enumerate at it.

Also if I declare `_attributeCount` static, I'm unable to use it in constructor and if I declar it non-static, I'm unable to use it `Range` method of Enumberable.

How will I initialize `_attributeValues` then?
How to declare `_attributeCount` static or non-static?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your trying to initialize the Dictionary by using a variable (_range) that is set at object creation.  This should be moved into the constructor.  It appears you are attempting to create three new attributes with keys 0,1,2 and values of new UtilCS.KeyCountMap().

If this is correct, then I would suggest using this as your constructor.

```
public Cluster(int _clusterID, int _attributeCount)
{
  this._clusterID = _clusterID;
  this._attributeCount = _attributeCount;
  _nkA = new Int32[_attributeCount];

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    _attributeValues.Add(i, new UtilCS.KeyCountMap<int>());
  }
}
```

However, since you are sending in _attributeCount I would say you could use that instead of 3.

```
public Cluster(int _clusterID, int _attributeCount)
{
  this._clusterID = _clusterID;
  this._attributeCount = _attributeCount;
  _nkA = new Int32[_attributeCount];

  for (var i = 0; i < _attributeCount; i++)
  {
    _attributeValues.Add(i, new UtilCS.KeyCountMap<int>());
  }
}
```

Comment: Then we don't need any enumeration over dictionary object to initialize? I hope `for()` loop will do the trick?

Comment: if you still wanted the _range which appears to be an enumeration of the keys ??  You could use a property such as
    public IEnumerable<Int32> _range { get{return _attributeValues.Keys; } }

Comment: The dictionary is initialized to an empty dictionary already in this line:  protected Dictionary<Int32, UtilCS.KeyCountMap<Int32>> _attributeValues = new Dictionary<Int32, UtilCS.KeyCountMap<Int32>>();

Comment: But if we are using for loop in constructor for initializing same, it'll create new attributes and values (whatever the value of `_attributeCount` be) am I right?

Comment: It appears you are thinking along the lines of an array where you would need to initialize it to a specific size and then you can add values later, up to that size but not beyond.  Dictionary's are not like that, you initialize it to a new Dictionary and then you can just add KeyValuePairs to that dictionary.  It appears you are using a sequential key for every value, you can achieve this with a List<> and skip the Dictionary. This would allow you to add an arbitrary number of objects to each list.

Comment: But in list<> we'll not be able to store keyvaluepairs as we are able to store in a dictionary

Comment: Correct, list would not be KeyValuePair, but if you are just setting the keys to 0,1,2,3... sequentially, a List will return your values the same way - _attributeValue[0] will be the first _attributeValue in the List as well as the first value in the dictionary.  If your keys have more meaning than just the first item then why is it be initialized with 0,1,2 and a new object with no unique values? If those keys have significance then definitely keep the dictionary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113166/discussion-between-twistedstem-and-taufel).

Answer (score 0):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, _attributeCount).ToList().ForEach(x => _attributeValues.Add(x, new UtilCS.KeyCountMap<Int32>()));
```

Comment: @Ponas--this is C#. Do we have ForEach() method here ?

Comment: @Taufel Yes, take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field" an error raised at `_attributeCount` inside `Range(0, _attributeCount)` method